# Problem with building Xml with Java (Jaxb)

Tags: java

So I want to build an Xml document. When I try to compile it drops error in this file (line 23, 24, 30, 31). The error message is:  illegal start of type.

```
package legoset;

import lombok.Data;
import movie.YearAdapter;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.Year;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = "name", "theme", "subtheme", "year", "pieces")
@Data
public class LegoSet {
    private String name;
    private String theme;
    private String subtheme;
    private int pieces;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "minifigs");
    @XmlElement(name = "minifig");
    private List<Minifig> minifigs;

    private Weight weight;
    private URL url;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "tags");
    @XmlElement(name = "tag");
    private Set<String> tags;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(YearAdapter.class)
    private Year year;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String number;
}
```

Comment: You should remove the semi-colons from the lines with the annotations on. They are not needed and will cause compilation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon after annotation.

e.g.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = "name", "theme", "subtheme", "year", "pieces")
@Data
public class LegoSet {
    private String name;
    private String theme;
    private String subtheme;
    private int pieces;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "minifigs")
    @XmlElement(name = "minifig")
    private List<Minifig> minifigs;

    private Weight weight;
    private URL url;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "tags")
    @XmlElement(name = "tag")
    private Set<String> tags;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(YearAdapter.class)
    private Year year;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String number;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped!